# Парс ссылки на картинку

Tags: php

А умеет ли PHP парсить картинку из определённого блока из стороннего сайта? Например, есть вот [такая ссылка](https://www.flickr.com/search/?sort=interestingness-desc&advanced=1&dimension_search_mode=min&height=1024&width=1024&orientation=landscape&media=photos&text=Moscow), в ней выдаются картинки по заданному мной параметру. Мне нужно выбрать самый первый блок с картинкой. div-блоки с картинками имеют следующие классы *view photo-list-photo-view awake*, и к такому блоку прикреплён стиль

```
transform: translate(0px, 0px); width: 329px; height: 177px; background-image: url("//c8.staticflickr.com/8/7583/16032928791_cf204d0bf0.jpg");
```

Так вот, как можно вытащить то, что находится в `background-image: url("")`?

Comment: 1) Воровать плохо. 2) У flickr есть удобный API.

Comment: У Flickr есть API, который не возвращает ссылку на картинку.

Comment: https://www.flickr.com/services/api/flickr.photos.search.html //  https://www.flickr.com/services/api/misc.urls.html Читайте в любом порядке ;)

Comment: @E_p вы, кажется, не понимаете задачу(или это я не объяснил должным образом). У себя на сервере я определяю город пользователя, а затем ищу на Flickr картинки того города, где проживает пользователь и вывожу ему ссылку на первую же картинку. Буду рад, если покажите мне в API такой раздел, который ищет картинки по запросу, например, "Moscow City".

Comment: Я вам на этот раздел ссылку кинул ;).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно пользоваться Flickr API.

https://www.flickr.com/services/api/flickr.photos.search.html
https://www.flickr.com/services/api/explore/flickr.photos.search

Например:

```
https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.search&api_key=bdee43577101657efce0990856dab97a&tags=Moscow+City&format=json&nojsoncallback=1
```

**Не забываем свой ключ(api_key...)**

вернет

```
{ "photos": { "page": 1, "pages": 87, "perpage": 100, "total": "8663", 
    "photo": [
      { "id": "29457134244", "owner": "44585409@N02", "secret": "203e60661a", "server": "8557", "farm": 9, "title": "roofs", "ispublic": 1, "isfriend": 0, "isfamily": 0 },
      { "id": "29757447190", "owner": "90577632@N06", "secret": "04fb9ee384", "server": "8445", "farm": 9, "title": "", "ispublic": 1, "isfriend": 0, "isfamily": 0 },
      { "id": "28753181186", "owner": "129923608@N05", "secret": "39d6e5bdce", "server": "8553", "farm": 9, "title": "Moscow City", "ispublic": 1, "isfriend": 0, "isfamily": 0 },
      ...
      { "id": "28753176496", "owner": "129923608@N05", "secret": "6e9217bc35", "server": "8578", "farm": 9, "title": "", "ispublic": 1, "isfriend": 0, "isfamily": 0 }
] }, "stat": "ok" }
```

Если верить https://www.flickr.com/services/api/misc.urls.html, то

> https://farm{farm-id}.staticflickr.com/{server-id}/{id}*{secret}*[mstzb].jpg

https://farm9.staticflickr.com/8557/29457134244_203e60661a_z.jpg вернет 1-ю картинку 640х640.

что он и делает ;)

[image: ;)]

Comment: Премного благодарен

Answer (score 1):

Регулярное выражение с проверкой на корректность расширения файла:

```
$string = "transform: translate(0px, 0px); width: 329px; height: 177px; background-image: url('//c8.staticflickr.com/8/7583/16032928791_cf204d0bf0.jpg');";

$pattern ="/background-image:[ ]?url\([\'\"]?(?<url>.*?\.(?:png|jpg|jpeg|gif))/";

preg_match($pattern, $string,  $matches);

if (isset($matches['url'])) {
   echo $matches['url'];
}
```

Здесь для удобства используем наименование для группы захвата, которое будет называться url и отражаться в ассоциативный массив, если есть результаты.

Comment: Эта регулярка работает, но парсит ссылку на картинку не именно из первого блока с классом *photo-list-photo-view*, а просто первую попавшуюся картинку.

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать вытащить обычной регуляркой, но это немного грубо:

```
preg_match("/view photo-list-photo-view [^$]* url\((.*?)\)/", $page_html, $q)
$url_photo = $q[1]
```

Это самая "грубая" регулярка. Можно немного уточнить ее, если вариант подходит.
`$page_html` можно получить через `curl` или `file_get_contensts`

Comment: Почему "грубая"?

Comment: Потому что можно сделать регулярку немного точнее. Но в данном случае и эта должна исправно работать.

Comment: `Notice: Undefined offset: 1`

Comment: Регулярка не работает. $q возвращает пустой массив.

Comment: Поправил, теперь проверьте. Вроде работает.